# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerBoosting_create'

Tags: opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jauzC.png)

I just ran into this error. I have tried many ways as a solution and I want to show you the solution.

Go to the pypi site by clicking this link.

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBKab.png)

When I tried this my problem was solved. You may be wondering why I am sharing an issue for which I know the answer. I'm new around here and can't answer questions. This is the reason.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a comment and not a question

Answer (score 0):

First remove your installed opencv library

```
pip uninstall opencv_contrib_python
```

or

```
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless
```

try to install it last.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```