# module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerBoosting_create'

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

```
import cv2

trackers = [cv2.TrackerBoosting_create,
        cv2.TrackerMIL_create,
        cv2.TrackerKCF_create,
        cv2.TrackerTLD_create,
        cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create,
        cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create, 
        cv2.TrackerCSRT_create,
        cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create]
```

output:

```
module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerBoosting_create'
```

the version is 4.5.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528648/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-trackerboosting-create

Comment: @coding babo. cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()